# Allow only “Remote Desktop Users” to connect through RDP using Powershell

Tags: powershell, rdp, windows-server

I am writing a Powershell script to set up RDP on Windows Server. Under Local Security Policies, I need to set 'Allow log on through Remote Desktop Services' to allow only 'Remote Desktop Users'.

[image]

Is this possible to set via Powershell? Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Better ask this on superuser.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Group policy is what you are looking for. See MS documentation or, say, Serverfault.